# How to reuse Jenkins credentials without masking the PASSWORD in withCredentials.usernamePassword?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

## Background

- I'm using scripted pipelines and Shared Libraries.

All the implementation we have is under the src directory where I reuse the reference in pipelines:

```
def static myFunction(steps, context) {
  steps.withCredentials([steps.usernamePassword(
      credentialsId: 'credentialsId',
      usernameVariable: 'GITHUB_USERNAME',
      passwordVariable: 'GITHUB_PASSWORD')]) {

     // use of steps.env.GITHUB_PASSWORD
  }
}
```

- I need to make 2 API calls to Github Enterprise with the same Credentials, which is set as the UsernamePassword credentials
  Although the first call works as expected, the second call fails because of the **env.GITHUB_PASSWORD** value is **masked**
  Details

As described in https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin, the problem might be related to how the Credentials binding is masked when used more than once. That is, once we use ${env.PASSWORD} once, it will mask all the uses of the same value.

## Detail

I'm using curl to and I need to generate the URL

```
def teamMembersApi = sh(curl -H 'Authorization: token ${env.PASSWORD}' ${githubRepoApi}")
```

The response of this call is another API URL, which I created another URL with the "**teamMembersApi**". So, making the second call...

```
def teamMembers = sh("curl -H 'Authorization: token ${env.PASSWORD}' ${teamMembersApi}")
```

At this point, the value of **${env.PASSWORD}** is masked and, as a consequence, the second call fails because of invalid credentials

## Questions

As I understand, this is a result of the "masking" of values when accessed via any method that will cause a "**toString()**" will make it not available for reuse in Strings...

- How can I reuse the same credentials, even when they are eligible to be masked?

## Verifications

- I tried using 2 blocks of **steps.withCredentials**
- I tried using the **httpRequest** step to not refer to variable

Using httpRequest, I got **MalformedURLException** with a clearly well-formed URL... I made sure the URL was in String format and has the protocol...

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: https://github.company.com/org/repo
```

Comment: Your Shell script example encloses code in double quotes: `sh("...")`. According to [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/), code should be enclosed in single quotes: "Note the use of *single* quotes to define the script (implicit parameter to `sh`) ..."

Comment: Changing this might not fix the problem but your code should be more secure.

Comment: @groverboy Makes sense that the double-quotes is already masking the issue. But I was assuming we needed since it needs to bind it to the string... I will try that...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `username/password` inside `withCredentials` block for any times. But
keep in mind, the `username/password` can only survive inside `withCredentials` block.

I used the same `username/password` for twice in following code and it worked well.

```
node('docker') {
  withCredentials([steps.usernamePassword(
      credentialsId: 'ba2e4f46-56f1-4467-ae97-17b356d7f854',
      usernameVariable: 'JENKINS_USERNAME',
      passwordVariable: 'JENKINS_PASSWORD')]) {

     def log = sh(
         returnStdout: true,
         script: "curl -u ${env.JENKINS_USERNAME}:${env.JENKINS_PASSWORD} -k ${env.BUILD_URL}" + 'consoleText').trim()

     def pipelineSteps = sh(
         returnStdout: true,
         script: "curl -u ${env.JENKINS_USERNAME}:${env.JENKINS_PASSWORD} -k ${env.BUILD_URL}" + 'flowGraphTable').trim()

     echo '\n## build log ##\n' + log

     echo '\n## pipelineSteps ##\n' + pipelineSteps
  }

  echo "JENKINS_USERNAME: ${env.JENKINS_USERNAME}" 
  // print JENKINS_USERNAME: null 
  // because JENKINS_USERNAME's lifecycle is limited inside withCredentials blok.      
}
```

Another issue in your code,  if you did not specify option `returnStdout: true` for step `sh`, it should return null. Example:  `def output = sh('command')`,  `output` will be `null`

Comment: According to @groverboy on the comments above, the error was because of double-quotes, since it will mask the value permanently... Are you sure the second command succeeded??? I did not include `returnStdout` for simplicity on my example... Will test and verify before accepting answers...